# The Boundary of Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2^n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Of course, the series $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{2^n}}{n}$$ diverges on the set $e^{i2\pi\Delta},$ where $\Delta=\{\frac{m}{2^k}|k\in\mathbb{Z}_+,0\leq m<2^{k}\}$ is the set of dyadic rationals (which is dense in $[0,1]$). If you're unfamiliar, this is because
$$f(e^{i2\pi\frac{m}{2^k}})=\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}\frac{e^{i2\pi\frac{m}{2^{k-n}}}}{n}+\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty.$$
This immediately bars f from having any analytic continuations beyond the open unit disc. However, does f converge anywhere on the unit circle outside of this dense subset? If not, is there some property of boundaries of analytic functions that allows us to extend this dense divergence to the entire boundary?

Comment: It converges at almost every point.

Comment: @NDB Wow, really? Is there some general result that proves that?

Comment: By [Carleson's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4247018/1198684)

Comment: @NDB So any series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2^n}}{n^\frac{1}{p}},$ for $p\in[1,\infty)$ would also have this property?

Comment: $p>1/2$, right? Such that $2p>1$.

Comment: @NDB It looks like there may be a generalization of Carleson's to any L^p space for $q>1,$ so for any $pq>1,$ i.e. $p>1.$

Comment: Ah, yes. That's right.

Comment: @NDB Thank you for exposing me to this. This result is insanely non intuitive, because not only does f diverge on the dyadic rationals, it diverges to positive real infinity on the dyadic rationals, yet somehow f manages to converge almost everywhere in between them.

Comment: For this particular series one doesn't need the strong result of Carleson as for a lacunary trigonometric series like this one on the unit circle it is not hard to show that if the Caesaro means of the partial sums converge at a point, then the partial sums converge too at that point (in other words Caesaro summability at a point implies ordinary convergence at that point) and of course, Feijer theorem implies that that the Caesaro means converge ae